# Can my followers like/comment my Facebook posts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I suspect that despite my liberal settings my followers are unable to do anything else than share my posts. I would like to enable likes for them.

I am asking because in the picture below, when I click view as public, it only shows the option to share.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it is showing in the screenshot (first one) is correct. It is showing how your profile looks like for others who are **not** following you or are not your friend on Facebook. It is *not* showing how it looks for those who are already following you. To see that, change the *Public* option with any of your friends' names.

Look at the *Add Friend* and *Follow* options. They are there, so it is showing anyone can send you a friend request or follow you.

For more clarity you can look into your profile from someone's profile who is already following you. You will see *Like* and *Comment* options will be there (if post is public).

So your settings are fine, just make sure when you are posting something you have set the audience as Public.

Comment: You're saying my followers can see all that my friends are seeing? Since you say try view as a friend.

Comment: No, followers can see only your public post.